# I am getting an EOF Error and i am struggling with fixing it

Tags: string, eof

I get EOF error when i give my input at

```
operation = input("what do you want to do (+,-,/,*):")
```

Here is the code

```
def add(num1, num2): #function signature
    return num1 + num2

def sub(num1, num2): #function signature
    return num1 - num2

def div(num1, num2): #function signature
    return num1 / num2

def mul(num1, num2): #function signature
    return num1 * num2


def main():
    operation = input("what do you want to do (+,-,/,*):")
    if(operation != '+' and operation != '-' and operation != '/' and operation != '*'):
       print("you must enter a valid operation")
    else:
        var1 = int(input("Enter num1: "))
        var2 = int(input("Enter num2: "))
        if(operation == '+'):
            print(add(var1, var2))
        elif (operation == '-'):
            print (sub(var1, var2))
        elif (operation == '/'):
            print (div(var1, var2))
        else:
            print (mul(var1, var2))
main()
```

This is the error!

```
File "<string>", line 1
    +
    ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
```

Comment: python 2.7 or python 3?

Answer (score 0):

In python 2.7 input() runs the user input as expression.

So, on changing to `input()` to `raw_input()` should do!

```
operation = raw_input("what do you want to do (+,-,/,*):")
```

[This](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#input) should help!

Comment: kindly accept the answer if it answers your question!